# Как импортировать оформленную стилями компонент-кнопку и применить к ней дополнительные стили в React?

Tags: css, reactjs, стилизация

Есть общий компонет - кнопка со своими стилями. По задумке будет использоваться много раз в разных частях сайта. Стили кнопки включают в себя, естественно, лишь визуальные вещи.

Как мне сделать к ней, например, float: left, в месте куда вставляю?

Например, я вставляю эту кнопку в каком либо компоненте, импортируя её:

```
<Button className={style.myButton} buttonText='Нажми меня' />
```

...И последующее применение стилей классу myButton не работают.

Как решить проблему?

Comment: Кнопка внутри компонента так же имет свой класс.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил с помощью препроцессора Sass. Убрал импорт компонента. Создал обычную кнопку и присвоил класс myButton. Создал миксин со стилями кнопки и импортирую этот миксин в class myButton и везде, где нужна кнопка именно с таким оформлением.